# Ext4 reload tree

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, reload

I am newbie to EXT and I am having problem with reloading EXT 4 tree. I have been trying with:

```
Ext.tree.getLoader().load(tree.root);
Ext.tree.load(tree.root);
Ext.tree.getRootNode().reload();
Ext.tree.TreePanel.root.reload();
Ext.data.TreeStore.reload();
```

And nothing helped, I hope someone could clarify this to me, here is the code:
Edit: I have added complete code, as you can see everything is inside extOnReady method, I have removed var before var tree and still I got the same result

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'url1'
    },
    root: {
        text: 'TOPP',
        id: '1',
        expanded: true
    },
    folderSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }]
});

tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',{
    id:'company_tree',
    store: store,
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
        }
    },
    renderTo: 'tree-div',
    height: 300,
    width: 766,
    title: gettext('Companies'),
    useArrows: true,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [ {
            text: gettext('Collapse All'),
            handler: function(){
                tree.collapseAll();
            }
        }]
    }]
});
var loadingMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.get('tree-div'),{
    msg: gettext("Loading...")
});

tree.on('itemmove', function(tree, oldParent, newParent, index, options){

    if(confirm(gettext('Are you sure you want to move this company?'))){
        loadingMask.show();
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            scope: this,
            url: 'url2/',
            success:function(){
                loadingMask.hide();
            },
            params: {
                'ajaxAction[moveNode]':  '',
                index: index,
                nodeid: tree.data.id,
                parentNodeID: newParent.data.id,
                oldParentNodeID: oldParent.data.id
            }
        });
    }else{
        Ext.getCmp('company_tree').getStore.load();
    }
});
```

Also I have tried to reload through console[Ext.getCmp('company_tree').getStore.load();] and it worked. When I try it through code it returns an error regarding fly function

```
n is null
[Break On This Error]   

Ext.fly(n.firstChild ? n.firstChild : n).highlight(me.dropHighlightColor);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you really trying to call these methods directly on `Ext.tree` namespace or `Ext.tree.TreePanel` class? If so you really need to educate yourself on the difference between objects and classes.

And don't just attempt to guess what a method might be named. Had you looked it up from the [manual](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/) you would have found out that there is no such method as `reload` on Tree, TreeStore or TreeView.

What you need to call to reload the tree is the [load](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-method-load) method of TreeStore:

```
tree.getStore().load();
```

Comment: tree.getStore is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

tree.getStore().load();

I've got this error
I understand tree is object, and Ext.tree.Panel is a class. And i am trying to do this on object(tree)

Comment: Are you sure that `tree` really is an instance of `Ext.tree.Panel` when you are calling `getStore()` on it? Add `console.log(tree)` above this that to find out what the `tree` variable holds.

Comment: @SrdjanRadisa also if you define `var tree` inside of `Ext.onReady`, the `tree` _local_ variable will still be undefined anywhere outside of `Ext.onReady`, that's a mistake some people make when they are first starting in extjs. It would cause an error like `tree.getStore is not a function` because the undefined variable `tree` doesn't have any functions. You could make it a global variable by deleting the word `var` in `var tree =` or just reference it correctly using an `itemId` or `id` config on your tree.

Comment: I have tried, but no results. I have edited the post now you have complete code, so you could have the big picture.

Comment: And yes I have done the console.log and there is no function getStore() in tree object.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. In the question you say that `getStore().load()` either worked or produced an error somewhere inside, but here you say that tree object has no getStore method. So how did it work for you if there is no such method?

Comment: it works when I remove `var` from `var tree =` And also works by using ID - Like user Geronimo said. Clearer now? Same code works differently in file and in console. As I see there is some [Bug relating the listeners](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135093-TreePanel-beforeitemmove-Bug) and the same thing happens with itemmove event in my code